# New tokens do not allow access to policy

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Have setup a Hashicorp Vault docker container, but seem unable to get database credentials when using a generated token, rather than the root.

```
error occurred: permission denied
```

Steps to recreate:

I created the latest container, got the root token and used it to authenticate.

Ran the following commands:

```
export VAULT_ADDR='http://127.0.0.1:8200'
vault secrets enable database
vault auth enable approle
vault write sys/policy/test policy='path "database/roles/" {capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]} path "auth/approle/login" { capabilities = [ "create", "read" ]} path "database/creds/" {capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]} path "secret/dbcreds" {capabilities = ["create", "update", "read"]} path "sys/mounts/" {capabilities = [ "create", "read", "update", "delete", "list" ]} path "database/" { capabilities = [ "create", "read", "update", "delete", "list" ]}'
vault write database/config/mssql plugin_name="mssql-database-plugin" root_rotation_statements="ALTER LOGIN [{{username}}] WITH PASSWORD = '{{password}}'" connection_url="sqlserver://{{username}}:{{password}}@sql:1433" allowed_roles="*,test" username="***MY_USER***" password="***MY_PASS***"
vault write database/roles/Tenant_1 db_name=mssql creation_statements="CREATE LOGIN [{{name}}] WITH PASSWORD = '{{password}}';USE [Tenant_1];CREATE USER [{{name}}] FOR LOGIN [{{name}}];ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER [{{name}}];" default_ttl="1h" max_ttl="24h"
vault write auth/approle/role/test secret_id_ttl=0 token_num_uses=0 token_ttl=20m token_max_ttl=30m secret_id_num_uses=0 policies="default, test"
vault read auth/approle/role/test/role-id
vault write -f auth/approle/role/test/secret-id
vault write auth/approle/login role_id=***role_id*** secret_id=***secret_id***
vault secrets enable -version=2 kv
```

I also tried replace 'vault write' with 'vault kv put', and got success for all commands.

So I call GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/database/creds/Tenant_1, using header:

```
X-Vault-Token
**Root-Token**
```

It works.

If I call POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/approle/login with a valid role/secret id, I get a token back successfully.  However, if I try to use this token instead of Root in the GET call, it gives permission denied.

Looking through the policy config, it looks to me like /database/creds is part of the policy.

If I do a token lookup on a generated one:

```
Key                 Value
---                 -----
accessor            PNe8WQiXnZvlFNEJekXO2es4
creation_time       1555517775
creation_ttl        20m
display_name        approle
entity_id           acc7558b-02b1-328d-4705-74f00ab9524b
expire_time         2019-04-17T16:36:15.6815637Z
explicit_max_ttl    0s
id                  s.iGkfsCUS6JX58SiDl8pfFN2K
issue_time          2019-04-17T16:16:15.6815627Z
meta                map[role_name:test]
num_uses            0
orphan              true
path                auth/approle/login
policies            [default test]
renewable           true
ttl                 16m35s
type                service
```

Looks good to me!?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Ok this wasted a good few hours, but have a solution for anyone else with similar problems.

My policies were missing /* from the end, so even though the token was valid, it didn't have permission to access those credentials.